# Codeigniter after renaming file for upload how do i save the new file name to my database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue with codeigniter file upload library. I am trying to upload multiple files (7 images), i renamed them and after which uploaded to my server file system. But i cannot get the new name to save in my database.

Here is my Controller

```
if (isset($_POST['carform']))
{
                $dir = './uploads/cars';
                $config['upload_path'] = $dir;
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '2048';
                $config['max_width']  = '1024';
                $config['max_height']  = '768';
                $config['remove_spaces'] = 'TRUE';
                $uid = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
                $config['file_name'] = time().$uid;
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            foreach($_FILES as $field => $file)
            {

                if($file['error'] == 0)
                {

                    // So lets upload
                    if ($this->upload->do_upload($field))
                    {


                        $data = array('upload' => $this->upload->data());

                        $this->cars_model->set_car($data);//end foreach loop.....
                        $id = $this->db->insert_id();
                redirect('/cars/details/'.$id.'');

                    }else
                    {
                        $errors = $this->upload->display_errors();
                        echo($errors);
                    }
                }

            }


        }//end if  statement ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a helper function within Codeigniter File Uploading Class: `$this->upload->data()`. In order to get the filename do this:

```
$my_data=$this->upload->data();
$file_name=$my_data['filename'];
```

check the manual [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

edit: 
to insert data into database assuming $filename is a string you need first explode it into an array

```
$filename="14010989464.jpg 140109894641.jpg 140109894642.jpg 140109894643.jpg 140109894644.jpg 140109894645.jpg 140109894646.jpg";
$fn=explode(' ',$filename);
```

then you can insert the data (imagename) into the column `img` of your table `test` like this:

```
foreach ($fn as $key=>$val){
    $data['img']=$fn[$key];
    $this->db->insert('test', $data);
}
```

Comment: In my case am uploading multiple images(7) of them and when i do print_r($filename) i get this result: 14010989464.jpg 140109894641.jpg 140109894642.jpg 140109894643.jpg 140109894644.jpg 140109894645.jpg 140109894646.jpg . My question now is How do i get the individual filename to save in my db.

Answer (score 0):

can use for

ex :

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++) //5 = total image
{
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'.$i)) 
{
    $data['error'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

}
else
{
    $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
    $data[$i] = $upload_data['file_name'];
}
}
    $data_x = array(

                'image1' =>  $data['1'],
                'image2' => $data['2'],
                'image3' => $data['3'],
                'image4' => $data['4'],
                'image5' => $data['5'],
    );
```